Get the creator of a token
I'm monitoring some pump tokens and I want to know who originally created the token, now , I've seen the following answer:
I need to get the creator of an SPL token that has been minted already
problem is, every pump token has the same updateAutority:
TSLvdd1pWpHVjahSpsvCXUbgwsL3JAcvokwaKt1eokM
so it's not the creator of the token. Again, the creators field for all the pump tokens is null, so, any suggestions?
Thanks

This is unreliable and not really a satisfying solution, but it does the job:
https://frontend-api.pump.fun/coins/3gSbBaMHEEC74dA38BDG2iGkBBoWNKsfx5VzgBHfpump
Just change the mint address in the url and you are good to go.

Thanks bro, this is what I was looking for!

Unfortunately, if you are fetching token metadata program details using either the DAS API or the various ways to fetch via UMI https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch, you'll only find the details that Pump has configured their program to add for the metadata.
A hack I was thinking, was to check the tx signers, but pump.fun uses a single signer to create the tx, Gsq567mLS6NH7bMTJmzLc4dZm3uDgBC6sHxmXxSgpump

Yep, I did the same thing. At this point, the only way to do it is to fetch all the transactions of a token, all of the way back to to TOKEN_CREATION witch for older tokens means traversing millions of transactions.
